# How can i implement GCM in meteor web application

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to Send push notifications from meteor website to android application using Google cloud messaging.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done it is to use the package `raix:push`.

To do this, first install the package, then set up a `config.push.json` file in your root directory. This file contains the settings for the push notifications. The most basic file you can have that allows you to use Google cloud messaging is just:

```
{
    "gcm":{
        "apiKey":"yourApiKey",
        "projectNumber": 000000000
    }
}
```

Then you can send a push notification by calling a meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    "sendPush": function(title, text, userId){
        Push.send({
            from: 'yourName', 
            title: title, 
            text: text, 
            query:{userId: userId}
        });
    }
});
```

and also calling:

```
Push.allow({
    // Change this to determine whether the user with id userId can send
    // the notification
    send: function(userId, notification) {
        return true; // Allow all users to send
    }
});
```

on the server.

The above method would send a push notification to a user with _id equal to userId. You can make the query more complicated to send multiple notifications at once, just keep in mind that the field with the user's id is called `userId`, since this package creates a new collection to emit notifications.

This package is documented quite well: https://github.com/raix/push. Just follow the instructions for android, and take a look at the simple example.

If you don't have an api key or project number, you can follow the instructions in the documentation to set up Google cloud messaging.